# Flutter debugging fails due to target has string "android-31"

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

So I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to get the app running with debugging inside VSCode.
I start the emulator, and then hit "Run and debug".

I get the following error:

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-31' in:
> C:\Users\97250\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

I have installed Android SDKs and build tools.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that my `android-31` inside the sdk folder was named `android-31.delete` for some reason.
Delete the folder and reinstall the SDK from Android Studio.